# Neo4j cross join on csv file in community edition

Tags: performance, neo4j, cross-join

New to neo4j and I have a csv file of 30 million rows, wherein I want to cross join that csv file and fetch data.

**Version using : Neo4j 4.0.3 community edition.
RAM 20 GB**
Suppose there are 10 columns from a1 to a10, following are conditions :

```
match(n:alSUBS_5May) WITH collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n1
UNWIND nodes as n2
WITH n1,n2
WHERE id(n1) < id(n2) and n1.p_id<>n2.p_id and n1.status<>n2.status and n1.phone=n2.phone and n1.code=n2.code create (n1)-[r:suspected]->(n2) 
return type(r)
```

I have tried also to optimize query , but query is taking a lot time and it fails after Java Heap space or browser gets hung.

I tried with dividing this file into two files then joining it, but it is also now running.

Please suggest effective query , which can be used in this case.

Comment: Can you give the full query, including the LOAD CSV portion? Or is this a post-processing step after you've loaded in the CSV?

Comment: it is a post processing step only, I have created nodes 30 million using periodic commit in 16 minutes. Now building relations among the nodes

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I'm putting this here instead of a comment so that I can use formatting. I think the below may work but it depends on how many relationships will be created. Neo4j is transactional so making a lot of changes in a single statement can cause memory issues.

The Cypher below works on collections of nodes whose phone and code properties match so, if that count is relatively small, this statement may complete. If not, you may have to execute it in batches passing in phones or codes as filter parameters.

Notice that I changed the CREATE to a MERGE. MERGE will only create the :suspected relationship if it doesn't already exist.

```
MATCH (n:alSUBS_5May) WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT [n.phone, n.code]) AS candidates
UNWIND candidates AS candidate
MATCH (n2:alSUBS_5May) WHERE n2.phone = candidate[0] AND n2.code = candidate[1]
WITH COLLECT(n2) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes as n1
UNWIND nodes as n2
WITH n1,n2
WHERE id(n1) < id(n2) 
  AND n1.p_id <> n2.p_id 
  AND n1.status <> n2.status 
MERGE (n1)-[r:suspected]->(n2) 
RETURN type(r)
```

Comment: Thanks @hoyski . I have loaded 30million nodes successfully, now after executing your query this is one error.                                                                                                   
Invalid input '>' (line 12, column 26 (offset: 374))
"MERGE (n1)-[r:suspected]->(n2)" .                                                                                              Also please tell me the way of filtering or batching the rows through apoc procedure , as i have tried few but still query is takling a lot time.

Comment: Also this has to be generated on complete 30 million file, need to find how many nodes are linked with this relation . so cannot apply filter parameters . Please suggest some other way.

Comment: I corrected the typo in the cypher statement so it should execute now but may still overflow the heap

Comment: If you need to break it into batches you can use https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/periodic-execution/ to break the update into multiple executions. You can count how many relations were created after all of the updates are complete with `MATCH ()-[r:suspected]->() RETURN COUNT(r)`. If there are existing :suspected relationships that you don't want to include in the count then you can set a boolean property, say `new`, on the relationships and count them with `MATCH ()-[r:suspected {new: true}]->() RETURN COUNT(r)`

Comment: i have tried with applying apoc.periodic.commit 1000 rows. But query is still running from 3 hours , can you please suggest in community edition with 20 GB ram and performing cross join on 30 million , how efficient and possible solution is this ,considering memory requirement . Also from your previous experiences . if possible in how time query will complete without fail ?

Comment: What indexes are in place?

Comment: Created composite index like this : CREATE INDEX BaseIndx  FOR (n:extractedBase)
ON (n.connectionStatus, n.phone,n.p_id,n.pincode)

Comment: Three hours may be about the best that can be done. Comparing 30 million nodes against each other is 900 trillion comparisons, but with indexes and filtering we can hopefully optimize it further. The index you posted doesn't cover the nodes in the query. The query is against the label :alSUBS_5May but that index is on the label :extractedBase. Please post the full apoc.periodic.commit command you ran.

Comment: it was a typo , this is the complete query , please suggest to optimise it :                                               
     call apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (n:alSUBS_5May) WITH COLLECT( [n.phone,n.pincode]) AS candidates UNWIND candidates AS candidate MATCH (n2:alSUBS_5May) WHERE n2.phone = candidate[0] AND n2.pincode = candidate[1] WITH COLLECT(n2) AS nodes UNWIND nodes as n1 UNWIND nodes as n2 WITH n1,n2 WHERE n1.parent_id <> n2.parent_id  AND n1.connectionStatus<> n2.connectionStatus with n2 limit $limit MERGE (n1)-[r:possible]->(n2) RETURN type(r)",
  {limit:10000})